# Find a line along a circle's perimeter?

Tags: trigonometry, circles

If I know coordinates of point $A$, coordinates of circle center $B$ and *r* as the radius of the circle, is it possible to calculate lines that are passing through point $A$ that are also tangent to the circle?

[image: Example of result]

*A* is the green point, *B* is the center of the red circle and I am trying to find out the blue lines.

Comment: For clarity, is 'a' an arbitrary point outside the circle? Is 'b' the circle's center? Are you looking for lines that run tangent to the circle? And last question, are you looking for an algebraic solution or a calculus solution?

Comment: @Sarah What does it mean to pass through the circumference?

Comment: b is the position of the center of the circle, a is the point.

Comment: By passing through the circumference, I mean a line that "brushes" the perimeter of a circle, as seen in the example above.

Comment: I might apply this later to a program, so it would be nice to have an algebraic solution.

Comment: Please edit the title and body of your Question.  The lines you ask about are evidently *tangents* to the circle drawn from a point outside of the circle.  The way you named the center of the circle and the point *outside* the circle from which the tangents are drawn is inconsistent between the opening paragraph and the paragraph below the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote coordinates of point $A$ with $(x_A, y_A)$ and center B with $(x_B, y_B)$. Suppose that tangent AT touches circle at point $T$ with coordinates $(x_T,y_T)$.

You have:

$$AB=\sqrt{(x_B-x_A)^2+(y_B-y_A)^2}\tag{1}$$

$$AT=\sqrt{AB^2-r^2}\tag{2}$$

Denote the angle between line AB and $x$-axis with $\alpha$ and the angle $\angle TAB$ with $\beta$. You can calculate the value of $\alpha$ from:

$$\alpha=\arctan\frac{y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A}\tag{3}$$

...and the angle $\beta$ from the right triangle $\triangle ATB$:

$$\beta=\arcsin\frac{r}{AB}\tag{4}$$

Note that the solution exists only if (2) makes sense ($AB\ge r$). And if you are using computers to do the calculation, you should always use function like $atan2$ to compute $\alpha$ from the right quadrant.

Coordinates of point T can be obtained from the following expressions:

$$x_T=x_A+AT \space \cos(\alpha \pm\beta)$$

$$y_T=y_A+ AT \space \sin(\alpha \pm\beta)$$

In general, you have two different solutions for $AB>r$ and only one, trivial, for $AB=r$ ($T\equiv A$).

Equations of tangents are:

$$y-y_A=(x-x_A)\tan(\alpha\pm\beta)$$